# jquery function not calling on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Below is my code, i just want to alert the "hi" and "hello" so that i can put my actual codes there.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
    document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='jquery-1.11.1.min.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
}
</script>

  <script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.css">
</head>

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    alert("hi");
    $('form[name="lgform"]').submit(function(evnt){
        evnt.preventDefault();
    });

    $("#btn_login").click(function(){       
        alert("hello");
    });

});
</script>

<body>
<form name="lgform">
<div>

<table id="table"  >
    <tr>

        <td width="35px"><input id="mob"  type="text" name="mob_nu"></td>

        <td width="35px"><input id="pswd"  type="password" name="pswd_vl"></td>

        <td width="100px"><input type="button" name="login_btn" id="btn_login" value="Login"></td>          
    </tr>

</table>
</div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

button click event is not working, i am using the same jquery library in some other places which is working fine. I have to call ajax in this page i need to call the button click without submitting the page, as i have few more buttons to add. Any piece of code is appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you debug this in the firebug may be some of your jquery libraries are loading properly

Comment: works fine for me. check this http://jsfiddle.net/n8roc39p/. as @MuhammadHisham suggested, are you missing any libraries? can you check your console for errors?

Comment: Code works fine for me too as per your requirement...I think you/moderator should close or delete this question.

Comment: @muhammed Hisham i am using eclipse

Comment: @Sushil no errors in console. but not working for me

Comment: do u get the alert on page load?

Answer (score 1):

when i tried your code i got this error

**Ignored call to 'alert()'. The document is sandboxed, and the 'allow-modals' keyword is not set**

and when i tried after replacing alert's with console.log then it is working fine.

Your code is working fine, replace alert's with console.log()